# ios idle time or put device to sleep

Tags: ios, time

I have a problem to which I can't seem to find any leads, any help will be much appreciated. I want in my ios app to put a device to sleep after a specific time. I know ipads/iphones automatically go to sleep on inactivity however I want my app to do this. Is there a way to achieve this.

Also can we determine the system idle time value and how much time is left until device goes to sleep?

Please let me know if I am unable to explain the question.

Regards

Yasir

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can an app force the device to sleep?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473990/can-an-app-force-the-device-to-sleep)

Comment: is there a way to find out the value of system idle time if manual sleep is not allowed?

Comment: No. This question might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363051/iphone-auto-lock-value

Answer (score 0):

You can only prevent your app from going to sleep from idling, but you can't force the device to go to sleep when you choose. There also doesn't appear to be any way to determine how long the device has been idle, or how long until it will go to sleep.

You can implement checks in your own app to see when the last time your app was interacted with, but that won't really tell you if the device was interacted with in some other way that might keep it awake.